# Page view in React Native app wont drag/scroll

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Im working on a react-native app and while one page [SearchResults](https://github.com/rahul1346/rcapp/blob/master/SearchResults.js) will drag and scroll through the results, this page [PeopleView](https://github.com/rahul1346/rcapp/blob/master/PeopleView.js) will not. Any idea as to whats happening?

Comment: The SearchPage components is render a ListView which has the scroll in it (in iOS UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView). The PeopleView page doesn't have neither a ListView nor a ScrollView therefore there isn't a scroll mechanism to drag the component.

Comment: Thanks. I have added ListView to the PeopleView page but now I am getting an infinite scroll of the same person's profile? Any idea why? Here is the updated code:

https://github.com/rahul1346/rcapp/blob/master/PeopleView.js

Comment: I think the problem is that you use the "people" variable all the time to populate the ListView.
Use "rowData" to fill all the views and the text views.
For instance replace:
    <Text style={styles.price}>{people.first_name} {people.last_name}</Text>
with
   <Text style={styles.price}>{rowData.first_name} {rowData.last_name}</Text>

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to rowData but now getting errors that "Undefined is not an object rowData.batch.name"

Comment: I'm adding the first comment as the answer of your question...

Answer (score 0):

The SearchPage components is render a ListView which has the scroll in it (in iOS UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView). 
The PeopleView page doesn't have neither a ListView nor a ScrollView therefore there isn't a scroll mechanism to drag the component.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to rowData but now getting errors that "Undefined is not an object rowData.batch.name"

Is it not in scope? I updated the code in the git if you want to check it out...

Comment: Any ideas as to whats going on?

Comment: Probably rowData doesn't have a field named "batch"

Comment: No it definitely does assuming it is the same object as people. Even when I delete that line, rowData.first_name and rowData.last_name give the same error as well. Perhaps rowData is not getting the this.props.people object properly?

Comment: I don't know. The console.log(rowData) shows the corrects data?